# css :hover height change not working

Tags: css, hover, height

I have this problem in my really easy `css` file, that I want to transform a `div` from `75px` in `height` and `width` with `:hover`, but it seems to only change the `width`.

```
#ich{
    transition: 2s;
    -moz-transition: 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: 2s; /* Opera */

    margin-top:40%;
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
    border-radius:35px;
    background-image:url(fb.jpg) ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
}

#ich:hover{
    width:300px!important;
    height:300x!important;
    background-size: 300px 300px;
}
```

The HTML is just a `div` with id `#ich` in the `body` part, nothing else.

Comment: In `height` definition you typed 300x instead of 300px

Comment: thx! stupid little p -.-

Comment: can i also change somehow, that the transition is coming from the center of the object?

Answer (score 6):

```
height:300px!important;
```

you just put "300x" instead of "300px"